# is there way to select everything from a list of model?

Tags: java, android-studio

asnafList is my list and getIc_number is my getter below is my code

asnafList.get(0).getIc_number();

I am trying to make sort of an authenticating feature for my apps and I use the above code in my if statement for the button. That code only get the 0 position of the list. So my question is, is there a way to get all of the position is the list to compare with the input from the user using the if statement?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question correctly. If you simply want to get every object out of the list, you probably want to do a simple for each loop.

Comment: How do I do the syntax to get the getter for the loop? the only way I know is through list.get(position).getter

Comment: you can use for or while loop, like below

for(int i =0 ; i <asnafList.size(); i++ ){
asnafList.get(i).getIc_number();
}

it will allow you to iterate through all items of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int number;
for(int i = 0; i < asnafList.size(); i++) {
    number = asnafList.get(i).getIc_number();
    if(number == YOUR_COMPARABLE_NUMBER) {
        // Compare and do anything here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly answer my question

Answer (score 0):

As Kushal answered, a for loop is useful for this. But I usually use a for each loop in this scenario. Not sure what type of objects are in the asnafList, but it will look something like this:

```
for(AsnafObject a : asnafList) {
    if(a.getIc_number() == YOUR_COMPARABLE_NUMBER) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

When you do this for loop, you basically iterate through every object in the asnafList, where AsnafObject is the classtype of your asnafList and a is the object which you can use to call any non-static methods of AsnafObject (or however your class is called)